# Calculating the number of days between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, days

I have a mySQL database.

I need to count the number of days between two dates.

My client is going to fill an input `hm_date` with January 1, 1979 via php form to create a new record.

I need a field `total_days` to calculate the total number of days from `hm_date` to the present day. I need this field to always update itself with each passing day.

How do I make `hm_date` to appear with total days and be always updated?

I asume this can be achieved server-side?

Should I use `strototime()` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to use MySQL's [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed as a value in days from one
>   date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time
>   expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the
>   calculation.

```
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-11-30 23:59:59','2010-12-31');
        -> -31
```

Based on your question I think you would want `DATE_DIFF(hm_date, CURRENT_DATE)`. Just make sure `hm_date` is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Comment: Is there an example anywhere for the syntax and how to write it?

Comment: is this right? mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('hm_date');
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT DATEDIFF('total_days');
        -> -31

Comment: You need to pass `DATE_DIFF()` two dates as parameters. Based on your question I *think* you would want `DATE_DIFF(hm_date, CURRENT_DATE)`. Just make sure `hm_date` is in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: And this can be server-side so i don't need to create php on the client-side?

Comment: Very grateful thank you for the follow through. Thank u.  :-)

Comment: Is this correct way?  SELECT * FROM `reg_add` WHERE DATE_DIFF(hm_date, total_days)

Comment: Try `SELECT DATE_DIFF(hm_date, total_days) AS days_diff FROM reg_add`

Comment: I'm getting this error:  #1305 - FUNCTION naturan8_41q.DATE_DIFF does not exist

Answer (score 1):

With PHP:

```
$daydiff = floor( ( strtotime( $endDate ) - strtotime( $startDate ) ) / 86400 );
```

$startDate and $endDate can be any valid date format explained here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Comment: A day is not always 24 hours.  During DST, it may be 23 or 25.  As such, this may sometimes fail.

Comment: The concept of "day difference" can not be programatically calculated without assuming a day is 24 hours. Governments can set a date for dst switching. And again it can't be 100% accurate with just dates, without inputting the actual time.

Comment: The fault in that is that a day *is* well defined.  It's just not *conveniently* defined.  DST is a bitch, but a bitch that you must tolerate.  Having a bug show up on DST-day is never a pleasant experience, especially when you look at the code and go "Awww...  I assume it was 24 hours."

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty easy but long.. Please follow following codes

```
<?php

  // Set timezone
  date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

  // Time format is UNIX timestamp or
  // PHP strtotime compatible strings
  function dateDiff($time1, $time2, $precision = 6) {
    // If not numeric then convert texts to unix timestamps
    if (!is_int($time1)) {
      $time1 = strtotime($time1);
    }
    if (!is_int($time2)) {
      $time2 = strtotime($time2);
    }

    // If time1 is bigger than time2
    // Then swap time1 and time2
    if ($time1 > $time2) {
      $ttime = $time1;
      $time1 = $time2;
      $time2 = $ttime;
    }

    // Set up intervals and diffs arrays
    $intervals = array('year','month','day','hour','minute','second');
    $diffs = array();

    // Loop thru all intervals
    foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
      // Set default diff to 0
      $diffs[$interval] = 0;
      // Create temp time from time1 and interval
      $ttime = strtotime("+1 " . $interval, $time1);
      // Loop until temp time is smaller than time2
      while ($time2 >= $ttime) {
    $time1 = $ttime;
    $diffs[$interval]++;
    // Create new temp time from time1 and interval
    $ttime = strtotime("+1 " . $interval, $time1);
      }
    }

    $count = 0;
    $times = array();
    // Loop thru all diffs
    foreach ($diffs as $interval => $value) {
      // Break if we have needed precission
      if ($count >= $precision) {
    break;
      }
      // Add value and interval 
      // if value is bigger than 0
      if ($value > 0) {
    // Add s if value is not 1
    if ($value != 1) {
      $interval .= "s";
    }
    // Add value and interval to times array
    $times[] = $value . " " . $interval;
    $count++;
      }
    }

    // Return string with times
    return implode(", ", $times);
  }

?>
```

Now try this and see how it shows the difference...

```
echo dateDiff("2010-01-26", "2004-01-26") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("2006-04-12 12:30:00", "1987-04-12 12:30:01") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("now", "now +2 months") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("now", "now -6 year -2 months -10 days") . "\n";
echo dateDiff("2009-01-26", "2004-01-26 15:38:11") . "\n";
```